# My character associated to Image Target barely moves

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm developing an android augmented reality game using unity 3d engine and vuforia extension where I need to move a character over a image target.

The problem is when I associate the character to the image target (as a child of image target) the movement is like the character is "glued" to the plane, it barely moves from his position, it moves very slowly.

I already tested without using augmented reality and the moving of the character is completly fine, so I dont know what am I doing wrong ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While animating on Unity, there's no difference of Vuforia and Non-vuforia.
Please explain how you animated the character, ie. through Animation or Code?

Comment: I didn't explain well, the character is animated through code, but the animation is fine, the animation runs at normal speed, but the position of the character doesnt change, or changes very slowly, is like he is doing some sort of "moonwalking"

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `object` to compulsorily be a child of the `ImageTarget`. AR will work both ways.

Wherever you place your `Object`, it will calculate the relative distance of the `ImageTarget` and place the Object there automatically. So if your Object is on the `Image Target`(not a child) It will show the object on top, as it is. Just make sure you don't make the `AR Camera` a parent/child of any other object.

As for the object following the object, you can simply use the Tracking functions to Enable and Disable tracking, so the object disappears

I really hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry can you send the link above again? It seems that has been removed. If I disable and enable tracking can I show the character only when the trackable image pattern is found?
I googled and I think that i have to associate a new script, or is another way?

Thanks jacob

Comment: Sorry, it looks like that question has been deleted. If you've still got that problem, feel free to ask for it again, I'll try and help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what it is! Check your `Inspector Panel` to see if you've got a `Rigidbody` Element. They're usually very difficult to handle, try unchecking the `Rigidbody` element and see if it's solves anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I dont have any rigid body, I only have the character controller. 


[Here is my player inspector](http://s8.postimg.org/d76niatx1/player_inspector.png) .


[And my hierarchy and scene](http://s3.postimg.org/vfzqizmfn/hirearchy_and_scene.png)


The strange thing is that if I dont associate the player to a image target the player moves at normal speed

Comment: Hey, then in that case take it out of the Image Target. There's no need for the object to compulsarily be a child of the Image Target. AR will work both ways.

Comment: but without a image target I cant put my characters in a real place like a table or something.. they just float around with the camera.. removes the purpose of my game

Comment: You're wrong with respect to that. Wherever you place your object, it will calculate the relative distance of the ImageTarget and place the Target there. So if your Object is on the Image Target(not a child) It will show the object on top, as it is. Just make sure you don't make the AR Camera a parent/child of anyother object.

Comment: I didnt know you could do that. Yeah youre right, and it works, it moves normal now. But when the camera loses the image target the character stands there floating around, is there anyway of just showing the characters when the image pattern is found? Thanks

Comment: Answered in the other answer.